How to add discount to custom line item in Shopware 6?
Is it possible to apply a discount to a custom line item product? That line item is not in the product repository. When we add a custom line item, the discount code does not apply to the custom line item product.
Here is controller code:
/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class SampleController extends StorefrontController
{
    /** @var CartService */
    private $cartService;

    /** @var QuantityPriceCalculator */
    private $calculator;

    public function __construct(
        CartService $cartService,
        QuantityPriceCalculator $calculator
    ) {
        $this->cartService = $cartService;
        $this->calculator = $calculator;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Context $context
     * @param SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|void
     * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
     * @Route("/sample/addlineitem", name="frontend.bfn.sample.addlineitem", methods={"GET","POST"}, defaults={"csrf_protected"=false}, options={"seo"=false})
     */
    public function addCustomLineItemToCart(Request $request, Context $context,SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext)
    {
        $productId = Uuid::randomHex();
        $lineItem = new LineItem($productId,'custom');

        $payload = [
            'lineType' => 'bfn_customLineItem'
        ];

        $quantityPriceDefinition = new QuantityPriceDefinition(12, new TaxRuleCollection([new TaxRule(19)]), 1);
        $price = $this->calculator->calculate($quantityPriceDefinition, $salesChannelContext);
        $lineItem->setPrice($price);
        $lineItem->setPayload($payload);
        $lineItem->setStackable(true);
        $lineItem->setRemovable(true);
        $lineItem->setLabel("Custom Line Item Test");

        $deliveryInformation = new DeliveryInformation(1000, 0.00, false);
        $lineItem->setDeliveryInformation($deliveryInformation);
        $lineItem->setPriceDefinition($quantityPriceDefinition);
        $lineItem->setReferencedId(Uuid::randomHex());
        $lineItem->setQuantity(1);

        $cart = $this->cartService->getCart($salesChannelContext->getToken(), $salesChannelContext);

        try {
            $this->cartService->add($cart, $lineItem, $salesChannelContext);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            die();
        }

        $this->cartService->recalculate($cart, $salesChannelContext);

        return $this->redirectToRoute('frontend.checkout.cart.page');
    }
}

The product was successfully added to the cart, but discount not apply to custom line item. Can you please help me?
We need to add shopware discount to custom line item.

I suppose that you need to apply/add discounts to cart manually, as you have a specific own line type, for which discounts are not applied automatically.
Take a look into that doc, it should help IMO https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/cart/add-cart-discounts.html#add-cart-discounts
